# geisview lists no device

Tags: multi-touch, touchegg

My initial target was to get multitouch gestures work in Spotify (3-finger swipe to change current song etc). I installed Synaptics, created a .xprofile file in home with

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
touchegg &
```

and added the corresponding lines to the touchegg.conf. However I first wanted to know if my touchpad does even support 3-finger gestures (In my windows-partition it works fine), so I installed geis and ran geisview in the terminal. 
No devices are shown in the window that pops up, just some classes like "Class 128 Added: Flick" with some details like "class name:b'Flick'". How can I get my Touchpad recognized for touchegg?